# How can I simulate a realistic rampup period for login access in JMeter?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, distribution, startup

I'd like to know if it is possible to add different access distributions to a load test in a web application.
My scenario:

- I want 100 users to be doing stuff at the same time. Therefore I have a loop doing some actions which takes longer than the 100 user login time.
- The users need to be logged in.

What I can do right now:

- I put a rampup time of 1 sec and all users collide during login and acess times are really high.
- I put a rampup time of 300seconds so that not all user logg in at the same time.

What I want:

- A more realistic scenario where not all users login at the same time but some do it. For example choose some distribution to be followed where it takes in average 3 seconds after the previos thread was started.

I have been playing some time with the timers but I think that is not valid as those do not take into account other threads.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "realistic"? There are at least [2 types of performance testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/) you can perform:

1. [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Software_load_testing) which checks the system performance under the **anticipated** load so you need to have the user arrivals details from the [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or current production metrics or from your [business analyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst), etc. but not by asking random people from Internet regarding how to properly test your application and not even providing a little bit of details
2. [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) which finds the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) of the application and the first [bottleneck](https://blog.qatestlab.com/2018/04/17/testing-system-bottlenecks/). In this case you start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding the acceptable threshold or errors start occurring.

You can also go for [Spike Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing) to simulate the situation when all the application users start i.e. sharp at 9 AM and the first thing they do is logging into the system.

If you have a specific users arrival pattern in mind and you don't know how to properly implement it share the exact details and most probably we shall be able to assist. In the meantime you can take a look at [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) available via JMeter Plugins project, it might be the case you will be able to implement everything yourself.